# Limiting the amount of times a value of a certain key can appear in JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, key-value, key-value-coding

I have an array within my JSON file which looks as follows:

```
{
 "commands": [
   {
     "user": "Rusty",
     "user_id": "83738373",
     "command_name": "TestCommand",
     "command_reply": "TestReply"
   }
 ] 
}
```

and so on. I want to limit the amount of commands to a certain user (recognized by the `user_id`) to 3 commands. I know I need to start by looping through each object but stuck at how to accomplish the next part.

I'd want it to look similar to this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfCommands.commands.length; i++) { 
  if (arrayOfCommands.commands.user_id appears more than 3 times) {
   return message.reply("You cannot make more than 3 commands.");
  }
}
```

Comment: Trying to ask it again ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could create an object that stores the number of commands by user id. Then just check the object to see if there are too many commands for a given user.

```js
let commands = [
   {
     "user": "Rusty",
     "user_id": "83738373",
     "command_name": "TestCommand",
     "command_reply": "TestReply"
   },
   {
     "user": "Rusty",
     "user_id": "83738373",
     "command_name": "SecondCommand",
     "command_reply": "TestReply"
   },
   {
     "user": "Rusty",
     "user_id": "83738373",
     "command_name": "ThirdCommand",
     "command_reply": "TestReply"
   },
   {
     "user": "Bart",
     "user_id": "83738233",
     "command_name": "ThirdCommand",
     "command_reply": "TestReply"
   },
   {
     "user": "Rusty",
     "user_id": "83738373",
     "command_name": "FourthCommand",
     "command_reply": "TestReply"
   }
 ];
 
 let userCommands = {};
 
 commands.forEach(command=>{
  if(!userCommands.hasOwnProperty(command.user_id))
    userCommands[command.user_id] = 0;
  userCommands[command.user_id]++;
 });

// Then quickly check if they have too many commands
if(userCommands["83738373"] > 3){
  console.log("Too many!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created two functions: One to return a simple boolean to check to see if the maximum has been exceeded and another to do the error message.

```
var userID = "83738373";
var arrayOfCommands =  {
     "commands": [
       {
          "user": "Rusty",
         "user_id": "83738373",
         "command_name": "TestCommand",
         "command_reply": "TestReply"
       }
     ] 
  }

//Function to return a simple boolean
function exceededMaximumComands(user){
    var count = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfCommands.commands.length; i++) { 
      if (arrayOfCommands.commands.user_id === userID) {
          count++;
          if(count > 2){ 
              return true;
          }
      }
    }
}

//Reusable function for throwing error message
function maximumExceeded(){
    //change this with your code
    message.reply("You cannot make more than 3 commands.");
}

//Where the code executes
var hasExceeded = exceededMaximumComands(userID);

//Check the result
if (hasExceeded){
  maximumExceeded();
}
```